# Glide multi instance with different transformation

Tags: android, dagger-2, android-glide

how I can have a different instance of Glide (or the proper component) that each one can have a different `RequestOptions`?

I have tried to create a different instance by using `Glide.with(app).serRequestOptions(...)`, but it looks it will apply it to the single instance and shared between all, is there a better way to handle this??

to explain more:

I have a generic interface for image loading

```
interface ImageLoader {
    fun load(view: ImageView, url: String)
}
```

and then I have 2 different implementaion of this:

```
class SquareImageLoader(context:Context):ImageLoader{
    private val requestManager = Glide.with(context)
            .setDefaultRequestOptions(RequestOptions())
    override fun load(view: ImageView, url: String) {
        requestManager.load(url).into(view)
    }
}
```

```
class CircularImageLoader(context:Context):ImageLoader{
    private val requestManager = Glide.with(context)
            .setDefaultRequestOptions(RequestOptions.centerCropTransform())
    override fun load(view: ImageView, url: String) {
        requestManager.load(url).into(view)
    }
}
```

the problem is `requestManager` in both classes is the same instance, so any modification on one of them will affect the other.